# Github pages not displaying images

Tags: image, github

I coded a custom site and I am trying to host it on GitHub to allow for version control and beta testing before launching it.

For some reason, the website isn't displaying my images - anywhere. Even though it works great locally.

[My Github](https://github.com/AustinMRobinson/portfolio_final)

Answer (score 1):

Your `portfolio_final` website serving the files from (`austinmrobinson.github.io/`) not from `portfolio_final/` directory. So, to show your images perfectly use `relative path` (just add `.` before image source) instead of `absolute path`.

Change image source:
**src="./images/service_Development.svg"** instead of 
**src="/images/service_Development.svg"**

**N.B.** Adding a `./` means current directory.

Comment: What about for background image url's in CSS? I tried it and it still isn't working. Maybe it needs a bit to populate.   I changed background-image: url(/images/hero2.PNG); to background-image: url(./images/hero2.PNG);

Comment: URL for `css` forlder should be `background-image: url(../images/hero2.PNG)`. Need to back parent directory: `../`

Comment: Unfortunately I tried that too and it's still not working.. not sure why. [Updated GitHub](https://github.com/AustinMRobinson/portfolio_final)

Comment: I found the issue! Change `*.PNG to *.png`. Working `url(../images/hero2.png` url